# Can we use UICollectionView within UITableViewCell : iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was wondering to implement `UICollectionView` within my **`UITableViewCell`**, so just want to know Is that possible. Any link that would guide me, would be much better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it's possible, just try it

Comment: since ios 9 you can use UIStackView for this requirement. You can check this also [AFTabledCollectionView](https://github.com/AshFurrow/AFTabledCollectionView)

Comment: i want to implement UICollectionView on my Custom UITableViewCell i.e, TableViewCell already contains UIImageView, Label and some buttons controls...

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can, place collection view inside UITableViewCell as like normal objects. and configure collection with help of tag or index path